# iOS Bundling failed 1933ms Unable to resolve "@test/lib1" from "apps/test/src/App.tsx"

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, nrwl-nx, nomachine-nx

I have started this project with @nx/expo. I have created several libs like for example "lib1". Everything looks good when I run the app with expo but when I run it from the simulator I get the following error: iOS Bundling failed 1933ms Unable to resolve "@test/lib1" from "apps/test/src/App.tsx".

@test/lib1 is how you import a library in nx after you have configured the path in tsconfig, example:

```
paths:{
 "@test/lib1": [
      "libs/test/src/index.ts"
    ],
}
```

How do I fix this in IOS too?